# Python multi-threading missing jobs

Tags: python, multithreading, automation, mechanize, webautomation

If I run the script step by step works perfectly, but when I'm using threading misses 50-60%. I'm using Python + mechanize module

```
#setting up the browser
mySite = 'http://example.com/managament.php?'
postData = {'UserID' : '', 'Action':'Delete'}
job_tab1_user1 = [1,2,3]
job_tab2_user1 = [4,5,6]
job_tab1_user2 = [7,8,9]
job_tab2_user2 = [10,12,13]
.... till user1000
#i want to point out that the lists are 100% different
def user1_jobs:
    for i in job_tab1_user1:
        browser.open("http://example.com/jobs.php?actions="+i) 
        browser.open(mySite, Post_data)
    for i in job_tab2_user1:
        browser.open("http://example.com/jobs.php?actions="+i) 
        browser.open(mySite, Post_data)
def user2_jobs:
    for i in job_tab1_user2:
        browser.open("http://example.com/jobs.php?actions="+i) 
        browser.open(mySite, Post_data)
    for i in job_tab2_user2:
        browser.open("http://example.com/jobs.php?actions="+i) 
        browser.open(mySite, Post_data)
... and so on till user 1000
```

And I call them in the end like this:

```
t_user1 = threading.Thread(target=user1_jobs, args=[])
t_user1.start()
t_user2 = threading.Thread(target=user2_jobs, args=[])
t_user2.start()
```

I have a similar script that sends like 200 request per second and all of them are processed. I also tried using time.sleep(2), but again is missing a lot.
Another question besides what is wrong with my script is if its way to compact this code, because I'm using 1000 users and the script reaches thousands of lines. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not use a `Queue.Queue` class to store all your jobs? You could then use a threadpool to handle the jobs on the queue.

Comment: When you say, "misses".. What is it exactly it misses to do?

Comment: @Torxed to send the post data to the server. Example: for user1 the jobs in tab1, for user2 the jobs in tab2. So it's complete randomly.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac I never used it. Can you tell me how to implemente for my code? Thanks

Comment: @MikeT `"+i)` will fail because you're appending an `int` to a `str` object. Secondly, so random web-requests fail? It might be of your connection rather than your code. Or the webserver might throttle you for hammering.

Comment: @Torxed is strange because step by step works perfectly and I also have a script that sends 3x more request per second than this one and the webserver doesnt have a problem

Comment: @MikeT I'd check the return-data of `browser.open(...)` and see what it tells, because your other scripts might handle `501 Internal Server Error` or `302 Temporarily Moved`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from threading import *

submits = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [6,7,8]]    

class worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, site, postdata, data):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.data = data
        self.site = site
        self.postdata = postdata
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        for i in self.data:
            browser.open("http://example.com/jobs.php?actions="+str(i))
            browser.open(self.site, self.postdata)
for obj in submits:
    worker('http://example.com/managament.php?', {'UserID' : '', 'Action':'Delete'}, submits)
```

Since the OP asked for it, here's a condensed/compressed version of the code.

or:

```
for index in range(0,1000):
    worker('http://example.com/managament.php?', {'UserID' : '', 'Action':'Delete'}, [i for i in range(1,4)])
```

If the data you want to send actually is a sequence of 3 integers `(1,2,3)` that inclines in a perfect order.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac In this particular instance yes, but could cause issues if updated or size was changed when iterating over it? If not it's still a bad idea IMO to teach something that's not universally functional and that can (if other variable types is used) cause troubles. Eveno tho you should use semaphor objects or queues :)

Comment: lets discuss this in chat.

Comment: I catch the idea, its a point of start. The first test (which involved a lot of modification of your script) ran nicely. Thank you for putting me on the right track. I will accept your answer

Comment: @MikeT Glad it worked, remember to check the output of things such as `browser.open` and post that in your question, usually there's a good hint inside the data as to what's wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full script that you can easily modify by changing the initial variables.
It creates a list dynamically and uses a generator to create the functions for each thread.
Currently it creates 1000 users, each with 2 tabs and 3 jobs.

```
# define your variables here
NUM_USERS = 1000
NUM_JOBS_PER_USER = 3
NUM_TABS_PER_USER = 2
URL_PART = "http://example.com/jobs.php?actions="

# populate our list of jobs
# the structure is like this: jobs[user][tab][job]

jobs = [[[0 for y in range(NUM_JOBS_PER_USER)] \
            for x in range(NUM_TABS_PER_USER)] \
            for x in range(NUM_USERS)]
p = 1
for i in range(NUM_USERS):
    for j in range(NUM_TABS_PER_USER):
        for k in range(NUM_JOBS_PER_USER):
            jobs[i][j][k] = p
            p += 1


# create a generator that builds our thread functions
def generateFunctions(jobs):
    for user in jobs:
        for tab in user:
            for job in tab:
                def f():
                    browser.open(URL_PART + str(job))
                    browser.open(mySite, Post_data)
                yield f

# create and start threads, add them to a list
# if we need to preserve handlers for later use
threads = []
for f in generateFunctions(jobs):
    thr = threading.Thread(target = f, args=[])
    thr.start()
    threads.append(thr)
```

Comment: I must say, you converted an already big set of code into an even bigger messier one. I'm sure it works but your `for` loops could be condensed quite a lot.

Comment: How is this bigger than a few thousands of lines? It could be condensed more, sure.